# Adding distinct in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Trying to add distinct based on specific column in following stored procedure but nothing works so far.

Here is the stored procedure where I am trying to add `Distinct` on column `Last4` which is part of the `Transactions` table.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @DBName varchar(50);
DECLARE @sp_executesql nvarchar(50);

DECLARE @Last30 datetime = DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE());
DECLARE @Last60 datetime = DATEADD(day, -30, @Last30);
DECLARE @Last90 datetime = DATEADD(day, -30, @Last60);

DECLARE @T Table 
           (
               DBName varchar(50), 
               Last30Cnt int, 
               Last60Cnt int, 
               Last90Cnt int
           );

DECLARE database_cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT name
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE name IN ('MyDatabase');

OPEN database_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DbName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --SELECT @DBName;   
    SELECT @sp_executesql = '[' + @DBName + '].[dbo].sp_executesql';
    ----******************  Create and Alt Tables *******************
    SET @SQL = N'
           SELECT ''' + @DBName  + ''' 
           , Last30Cnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TimeXStamp > @Last30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0)
           , Last60Cnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TimeXStamp > @Last60 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0)
           , Last90Cnt = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN TimeXStamp > @Last90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0)
           FROM Transactions
           WHERE
           TimeXStamp > @Last90 AND
           PaymentType = ''Credit'' 
           '

    INSERT INTO @T
        EXECUTE @sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Last30 datetime, @Last60 datetime, @Last90 datetime', @Last30 = @Last30, @Last60 = @Last60, @Last90 = @Last90;

    FETCH NEXT FROM database_cursor INTO @DBName
END

CLOSE database_cursor
DEALLOCATE database_cursor  

SELECT *
FROM @T
ORDER BY DBName
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` in SQL Server always applies to the **entire row** - not just a single column ...

Comment: you need to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and your desired results. 99.9% sure you also don't need a cursor, but that's OT.